# Emulating a negative lookbehind of unknown width in PCRE

Tags: regex, pcre

I have the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/G8Vrow/7):

```
(?<=:)\s*\w+
```

I want to only extract `comp` or  `comp` from the string:

```
savedPosition: comp;
CURLSCHET.NREC ('qwertyuiop'): noprotect;
```

I want to avoid matching cases like `noprotect` when there is a `(` or `)` anywhere before the required pattern.

Comment: Just to make it clear: you have a multiline string and you want to match specific words on lines not containing `(` and `)`? Also, do you really want to get empty matches, too? I think you need `\w+`, not `\w*`.

Comment: If the line is `: noprotect; (word)`, do you want to extract `noprotect`? The solutions will be different for the cases when a whole line should not contain `(` and `)` and when there should be no `(` and `)` before a `word` on a line.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, thank you for a tip in first comment.

Yes, i want to extract `noprotect` if the line is `: noprotect; (word)`

Comment: @skaborik then you can look into my answer. I think it covers your problem

Comment: It is mind breaking, since I actually do not know all details. Try [`(?m)(?:^|\G)[^()\n]*?:\h*\K\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/KGiF3E/2) - this will fetch multiple occurrences of the matches before the first `(` or `)` on a line.

Comment: Please check my suggestion. If it does not work, you must answer the questions in my first comment and probably add more examples to the question.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, it seems that it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A negative lookbehind of unknown width is not supported by PCRE (.NET does, it would look [like this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5b%5e%28%29%5cn%5d*%3f%29%3a%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*%28%5cw%2b%29&i=savedPosition%3a+comp%3b%0d%0a%0d%0aCURLSCHET.NREC+%28%27qwertyuiop%27%29%3a+noprotect%3b%0d%0aTEXT+%3a+noprotect%3b+text+here+and%3a+yeah+%28word%29+some+more%3a++noway+&o=m) there), but you just can extract all matches on every line before the first `(` or `)` using a combination of `\G` and `\K` operators with the help of a negated character class `[^()]` that would match any char but `(` and `)`.

You may use

```
(?m)(?:^|\G)[^()\n]*?:\h*\K\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KGiF3E/2)

**Details**

- `(?m)` - MULTILINE mode on
- `(?:^|\G)` - match start of a string/line or the end of the previous match
- `[^()\n]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `(`, `)` and newline, as few as possible
- `:` - a colon
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all the text matched so far
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this then:

```
[^\(\):]*:\s*(\w*)
```

Explanation:

1. `[^\(\):]*:` capture everything that doesn't have ( and ( and :
2. `:` folowed by :
3. `\s*` followed by zero or more whitespace character
4. `\w*` followed by word of zero or more length

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G8Vrow/9)

**Alternative:**

If you don't want to match the earlier part then you can also try this solution:

```
^(?=[^\(\):]*:).*:\s*\K(\w*)
```

[Alternative Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G8Vrow/10)

Comment: Your first pattern was a good idea, except that a start of the line anchor is needed. `(?m)^[^():]*:\h*\K\w+`

Answer (score 0):

[`: *\K\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/G8Vrow/12)

```
: matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
 *
matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\K resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
\w+
matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```